# Keep getting invalid path for passlist for some reason

Tags: python, visual-studio

```
from os.path import exists
from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentTypeError

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, username, threads, passlist_path, is_color):
        self.bruter = None
        self.resume = False
        self.is_alive = True
        self.threads = threads
        self.username = username
        self.passlist_path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\instagrammaster"
        self.display = Display(is_color=is_color)

    def passlist_path_exists(self):
        if not exists(self.passlist_path):
            self.display.warning('Invalid path to password list')
            return False
        return True


def args():
    args = ArgumentParser()
    args.add_argument('username', help='email or username')
    args.add_argument('passlist', help='password list')
    args.add_argument('-nc', '--no-color', dest='color',
                      action='store_true', help='disable colors')
    args.add_argument('-m', '--mode', default=2, type=valid_int,
                      help='modes: 0 => 32 bots; 1 => 16 bots; 2 => 8 bots; 3 => 4 bots')
    return args.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if int(python_version()[0]) < 3:
        print('[!] Please use Python 3')
        exit()

    arugments = args()
    mode = arugments.mode
    username = arugments.username
    passlist = arugments.passlist
    is_color = True if not arugments.color else False
    Engine(username, modes[mode], passlist, is_color).start()
```

After I set `python3 instagram.py username passlist.txt -m 2`,

It says invalid path for some reason and it was working for a little time and then suddenly started to give me the error.

Comment: You pass `passlist` to `Engine`, however, that parameter is ignored in the `__init__()` method.

Comment: any feedback on how to fix it ?

Comment: Your code has: `self.passlist_path = "C:\\ ... ` and then `if not exists(self.passlist_path):` so you have to tell me what is wrong. I don't have access to your machine.

Comment: Did you mean: `self.passlist_path = passlist_path`?

Comment: no , i mean the path is correct and the txt file on the same folder with the project , it should find the path but its not

Comment: So the path is correct or not. It cannot be both. Do you want to access the text file? If so, you need to save its name somewhere.

Comment: i did but still the same , im pretty sure i wrote everything correctly and it was working but now its not

Answer (score 1):

Copy the path of password file and then add the file name along with extension:
/home/guman/Instagram-/passwordlist.txt.